# Forcing an activity to be added to the history stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which is declared in my manifest with `android:noHistory="true"`, and 90% of the time, this is the desired functionality.  This particular activity doesn't need to be saved in the application's history, and the application's UI flow is greatly complicated when it is in the history and needs to be manually removed by calling `finish()` every time the activity would otherwise be added to the stack.

The problem is, that this activity has the ability for the user to send an email, which is of course accomplished by creating an Intent with the `ACTION_SEND` property.  When the user presses the "back" button from this activity, the next one to be shown in the stack is actually the one underneath my activity.  Is there any way that I can force Android to add my activity in the history stack before presenting the `ACTION_SEND` intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I look forward to be proven wrong but I believe that the history stack is updated when the activity is created. At first I would suggest the rather hackish solution of launching a "proxy" intent that would be pushed onto the stack which could then call the e-mail intent and would be smart enough to launch the proper intent on the way back.

I'll update my answer if I find something in my notes.